# Add-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' runs in ISE but not from .Net Process.Start command

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint

I have an automation issue that I've tracked down to the following situation:

The PS script is being loaded via process.start in a C# program.  If I run the script in the ISE, it runs fine. When running via process.start, it fails on the command:

```
Add-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'
```

With the error:

```
Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4.
```

The command I'm using for process.start in .net is:

```
var Arguments @"-version 4.0 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noexit -file """ + filePath + @""" -XmlString """ + args + @""" -Verb RunAs"
var FileName = "powershell.exe"

var process = Process.Start(FileName, Arguments);
```

filePath is the path to the powershell script that is being executed.

This runs and attempts to run the script, but fails on the command shown above inside the script. The user account is the admin service account for the machine. The issue seems to be in how the .Net program is starting PowerShell, as I can run this script and these commands via the ISE and console if I do it manually (under the same service account).  I just can't seem to find some combination of tricks to get the .Net program to be able to execute the PowerShell script under the correct profile, I guess.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Add this to your script and compare results: `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`.

Comment: Interesting... it's True in ISE and when I run a console manually, but False when executed via the .Net program.

Comment: Got it working, just had to compile the .Net program for x64.  Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PetSerAl's request was spot-on... when running the PowerShell script via the .Net program, it was running under x86, but when running it via ISE, it was running in x64.  I re-compiled the .Net program against x64 and everything now works.

Thanks for the advice!